# Sqlite удаление дубликатов

Tags: sql, sqlite

Здравствуйте.Нужно удалить дубликаты в sqlite.Написал вот такой запрос, но пишет ошибку no such column tmp.id. таблица tmp есть она полный дубликат variant. Огромная просьба помочь.

> ```
> delete from variant
>  WHERE (variant.id < tmp.id )
>  AND (variant.user_id=tmp.user_id)
>  AND (variant.test_id=tmp.test_id)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем запросе такой таблицы нет нет.

Я не знаю синтакис sql в sqlite, в MS SQL я бы переписал запрос так:

```
delete from v
       from variant v
            inner join tmp t
                    on v.user_id=t.user_id
                   AND v.test_id=t.test_id
 WHERE v.id < t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

> tmp.id

Откуда в запросе возьмётся некая таблица tmp?

Comment: она есть в базе. в mysql это бы точно работало. А что  в sqllite не так?

Answer (score 0):

Не понял, о каких дубликатах идет речь, и не знаю диалекта sqlite, но попробуйте такой вариант:

```
delete from variant
     WHERE exists (select 1 from tmp where
    variant.id < tmp.id 
     AND variant.user_id=tmp.user_id
     AND variant.test_id=tmp.test_id
        )
```